# Strings containing " - " always break onto newline with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm fairly new to YAML, within a Python 3.7 project, and decided to use ruamel.yaml to get me started.  I intend to use it to store metadata associated with some video files.

I am creating YAML files with the following code:

```
data[filename] = [{'video': video_path},
                  {'key_frame': frame_path},
                  {'processed': get_timestamp()}]
yaml.dump(data, file_handle)
```

The created YAML file looks like this:

```
video.mp4:
- video: /Users/xyz/video.mp4
- key_frame: /Users/xyz/imgOutput/frame
    - Trigger.jpg
- processed: '2018-07-26 17:09:06'
```

The issue is that the key_frame is a file called "frame - Trigger.jpg".  However, the line always breaks at the " - " (i.e. space-dash-space) in the filename.  Result is something that, as a human-readable file, it looks very wrong.  In fact, it's processed correctly when it's read back in (using yaml.open), and treated as a single string filename as it should be.  It's just the formatting in the YAML file that's wrong.

Any thoughts on the cause?  Is this expected behaviour?  I've tried many different ways of quoting the string in case that's it (which doesn't make a difference - even quoted it will split over the line), but fundamentally it does work, from a code sense - but as YAML's big selling point is human-readable files, it'd be nice to understand what's causing it and how to fix it.

Comment: Done a little more experimenting:
 - If the string is `frame - trigger.jpg`, it breaks as above (dash on new line).
 - If the string is `frame- trigger.jpg`, it breaks (but keeps dash on first line).
 - If the string is `frame -trigger.jpg`, it breaks (and dash is on new line).
 - If the string is `frame-trigger.jpg`, it doesn't break the line.
So essentially, a dash with a space on either or both sides causes a newline to be added to the formatting, but that newline is ignored when ruamel.yaml reads it back in.

Comment: If your question is incomplete, don't add a comment, update the question with the additional information. Do **not** use **Edit:** followed by the new text: always make sure the text is a single coherent whole. As indicated in my answer **always** provide a minimal but full working program that produces the output (or the error). You chance closure of your post if you don't; it is much easier to spot where you go wrong; and you might find the solution in the process of minimizing the program to reproduce unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In YAML plain scalars (i.e. the ones without single or double quotes) can be wrapped to an indented newline on whitespace. That is what's happening.

To reproduce this is difficult as your question is quite incomplete, but some things can be easily seen from the output:

- `data` is a `dict`
- `filename`, `video_path`, and `frame_path` are defined as strings.
- `file_handle` is probably some file stream opened for writing.

Others are less easily deduced:

- `get_timestamp()` doesn't return a `datetime.datetime()` instance as one would expect from its name, but a string representation thereof. To prevent this string from being interpreted as a timestamp, it has to be quoted.
- you are using the default `YAML()` instance (which equals `typ='rt'`), as the non-default ones would write the leaf mappings in flow style ( `- {video: /Users/xyz/video.mp4}`, etc.)

With that and the appropriate `import`s you can make a functioning program:

```
import datetime
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')

def get_timestamp():
    return datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 26, 17, 9, 6).isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='seconds')

data = {}
filename = 'video.mp4'
video_path = '/Users/xyz/video.mp4'
frame_path = '/Users/xyz/imgOutput/frame - Trigger.jpg'
file_handle = sys.stdout

data[filename] = [{'video': video_path},
                  {'key_frame': frame_path},
                  {'processed': get_timestamp()}]
yaml.dump(data, file_handle)
```

and this outputs:

```
video.mp4:
- video: /Users/xyz/video.mp4
- key_frame: /Users/xyz/imgOutput/frame - Trigger.jpg
- processed: '2018-07-26 17:09:06'
```

So we forgot something and that is:

```
yaml.width = 24  # range from 24-38 inclusive
```

with that you get your output:

```
video.mp4:
- video: /Users/xyz/video.mp4
- key_frame: /Users/xyz/imgOutput/frame
    - Trigger.jpg
- processed: '2018-07-26 17:09:06'
```

so just remove the `yaml.width =` line and you should be all set.

---

Next time please provide a minimal, but complete, functioning program that actually produces the output.

My guess is that your frame_path is much longer that you show here, and that you don't have a user `xyz`. That causes you to get over the default width (defined in the emitter to be `80`) and the plain scalar to wrap. Just set  `yaml.width = 4096` or whatever is necessary for your scalar length and nesting depth.

When in doubt if the YAML output is correct, read it back in (using an   `YAML(typ='safe').load(input_stream)`, it should produce the original data.

Comment: thanks for such a comprehensive answer.  Apologies for missing some details from the question, I was trying to focus on the bits I thought were most relevant.  But absolutely agree that some minimal functioning code would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try str(frame_path)

`data[filename] = [{'video': video_path},
                  {'key_frame': str(frame_path)},
                  {'processed': get_timestamp()}]`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately - exactly the same result.

Comment: Just to add, also tried using `DoubleQuotedScalarString` from ruamel, which explicitly includes the \ (backslash) line break at the end of the first line and start of the second.  Using `SingleQuotedScalarString` adds the single quotes as you'd expect, but still adds a line break before the " - ".

Comment: @DaveWalker - Not sure if this is a help but may be try this:
add '|' or '>' before '-' in your path

```frame_path = '/Users/xyz/imgOutput/frame |- Trigger.jpg'
or 
frame_path = '/Users/xyz/imgOutput/frame >- Trigger.jpg'```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the dash. If the string is longer than a certain threshold it will break at the first **space** after that. The examples you gave do not reproduce this behaviour for me, but longer strings do.

The generated YAML is valid. Any string, if quoted or not, can be broken up to several lines.

Maybe you can adjust the threshold in ruamel. I can't find anything in the documentation, though.

(See also my article [Strings in YAML](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html))

Comment: Ahh that's it - it was just the fact it was the first space in a long string, and ruamel breaks strings longer than a certain point.  Thank you!  :O)

Comment: Just to confirm you can adjust the line length / wrapping threshold by setting `yaml.width = 240` (choose your own value, obviously).  Fixes it for me.

Comment: @tinita The documentation has one reference to set the width, without explicit explanation, in [this section](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#transparent-usage-of-new-and-old-api). Of course the generic explanation given in the documentation that if you previously (or in PyYAML) used a keyword argument to `safe_load()` you can set that keyword as attribute on the `YAML()` instance, applies here as well.

Comment: @DaveWalker setting that to 240 is not necessary if the path to `frame - Trigger.jpg` really is just 21 characters long.

Comment: @Anthon thanks, it is actually a longer path (more like ~100 characters) but cut down for clarity / brevity here.  240 seemed like a nice round-ish number, not chosen for any particular reason.